org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection
I have a java application that accesses several services.  They've always worked correctly, and then all of a sudden I get the following error when trying to run one of them:
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection

I know that the username and password are correct, and that it is only affecting one service even though all of them use the same process.
I've pasted the stack trace below.
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:774) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:688) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]



Add the complete stack trace of the error to the question.

Just added the stack trace p- thank you

Seems like the system can't reach the datasource... did you checked that Oracle DBMS is on service? can you check connection with server(like using external database viewer tools, ping command, etc)?

Yep.  I can connect to the database using sqldeveloper and any of the other services.

Use [code block] format for logs and code, otherwise is hard to read it. The application failed to connect to the database. You'll have to find out why. We can not know.

Have there been any updates (lib, OS, IDE, etc) or network policy changes? This can impact your application without you directly modifying the code or configuration.
I provide support on legacy systems, which used the TLS 1.1 protocol and were no longer supported. At the company I work for, the newest TLS protocol has been enabled. Then, out of nowhere, the system stopped accessing other applications.
Your case may be similar.
To solve the problem, we implemented a simple Ruby on Rails application, which served as a proxy between the legacy applications and the rest of the applications on the network.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
